# Child theme modifications not showing up

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, permalinks

i am working on  a job-portal site and i am little stuck into one situation . I uploaded a child theme and activated it. The child theme is activated successfully but it dosent show changes that i do in child theme....for example :- i want to do changes in resume.php file and its path is wp-content/themes/workscout/inc/resume.php ;;;; so insted of directly do changes in core files i decided to do changes in theme file so i did this  wp-content/themes/workscout-child/inc/resume.php and i did changes in resume.php file...........but the changes of child theme were now showing up..... if i do changes in main core files then the changes will show, but if i do in child theme then i dosent work.

Things i did to fix the error but didnt worked:-
(1). Reactivated child theme multiple times.
(2). Deleted browser and plugin cache.
(3). Updated permalinks.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. **THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all files of child theme and upload again fresh file(Upload from cpanel directly) and activate the child theme i hope it will be helpful for you as we had thanks.

Comment: i tried this also